# For any integers $a,b$ the relatively prime integers $m,n$ giving $am + bn = 0$ are unique.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can prove for any integers $a,b$ that a choice of relatively prime $(m,n)$ gives $am + bn = 0$:

1) Set $m$ to $-b$

2) Set $n$ to $a$

3) Divide $m$ and $n$ by $d = gcd(a,b)$.

4) $m$ and $n$ are now relatively prime and give the desired sum.

I want to show that no other relatively prime choice $(m', n')$ exists but have been unable to show how. A good strategy is to assume the existence of an alternate pair and then show it must really be the original pair, but I cannot make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: $a=3$ and $b=2$; you can choose $m=2$, $n=-3$, but also $m=-2$ and $n=3$. So the uniqueness is up to multiplication by $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $am+bn=0$ if and only if $\frac{m}n=-\frac{b}a$. If $\frac{m'}{n'}=\frac{m}n$, then $m'n=mn'$, so $n\mid mn'$. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, this implies ... what?

Comment: It implies that $n$ has to divide $n'$. If $n$ divides $n'$, then $n$ must either be $1$ or $n'$. If $n = 1$ and $n \not = n'$, then $\frac{m'}{n'}$ to equal $\frac{m}{n}$, it must be the case that $m'$ is divisible by $n'$ -- but this would contradict our hypothesis that $m'$ and $n'$ are relatively prime. So $n$ must be $n'$.

Comment: Wait. "$n$ must be either 1 or $n'$ " is not true.

Comment: @Muno: Your initial conclusion, that $n\mid n'$, is correct, but after that you’re working much too hard. Let $n'=kn$ for some integer $k$. What must $m'$ be in terms of $m$? And what common factor do $m'$ and $n'$ have if they are different from $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Then since $\frac{m'}{m} = \frac{n'}{n}$, we have $\frac{m'}{m} = k$, meaning that $m' = km$. So $m'$ and $n'$ aren't relatively prime after all, because we also have $n' = kn$

Comment: @Muno: That’s right: either $m'$ and $n'$ aren’t relatively prime, or they’re $m$ and $n$, respectively. This shows that $m$ and $n$ are unique.